# Variável não-estática não pode ser referenciada de contexto não-estático

Tags: java, array

Estou utilizando um contexto em que possuo uma variável do tipo array com referência a outra classe.
Ao tentar declara o objeto-instanciado da classe e declarar seu tamanho é retornado este erro e gostaria de entender o porquê:

> non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

A linha de erro é **`e1.empregados = new Funcionario[TAM];`** em:

```
public class EmpresaTest
{
public static int posicao = 0;
public static boolean t = true;
public final int TAM = 5;



public static void main(String[] args)
{


    Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();
    Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario();
    Funcionario f3 = new Funcionario();
    Funcionario f4 = new Funcionario();

    Empresa e1 = new Empresa();

    e1.empregados = new Funcionario[TAM];

    t = Booelan.parseBoolean(e1.adicionaEmpregado(f1));
    System.out.println("T: " + t);

    e1.adicionaEmpregado(f2);
    e1.adicionaEmpregado(f3);

    e1.contemFuncionario(f1);
    e1.contemFuncionario(f2);
    e1.contemFuncionario(f3);
    e1.contemFuncionario(f4);


    /*e1.empregados[0] = f1;
    e1.empregados[1] = f2;
    e1.empregados[2] = f3;*/
    }
    }

public class Empresa
{    
public  int idEmpresa;
public  int razaoSocial;
public  String cnpj;
public  Funcionario empregados[];

public int getIdEmpresa() {
    return idEmpresa;
}

public void setIdEmpresa(int idEmpresa) {
    this.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
}

public int getRazaoSocial() {
    return razaoSocial;
}

public void setRazaoSocial(int razaoSocial) {
    this.razaoSocial = razaoSocial;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}

public Funcionario[] getEmpregados() {
    return empregados;
}

public void setEmpregados(Funcionario[] empregados) {
    this.empregados = empregados;
}

public void adicionaEmpregado(Funcionario f)
{
    int i = 0;

    if(this.empregados[i] != null)
    {
        this.empregados[i] = f;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Não dá para adicionar mais funcionários");
    }

    /*for(int i = 0; i < empregados.length; i++)
    {
        this.empregados[i] = f;
    } */

}

public void mostrarEmpregados()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < empregados.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Valor: " + i + " é o empregado: " + this.empregados[i]);
    }
}

boolean contemFuncionario(Funcionario f)
{
    boolean func = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < empregados.length; i++)
    {
        if(this.empregados[i] == f)
        {
            System.out.println("Empregado existente!");
            func = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Não encontrado!");
            func = false;
        }
    }
    return func;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema nesse caso é que está tentando acessar uma variável de instância em um contexto estático.

**Variáveis de instância** pertencem ao escopo de um determinado objeto, uma instância de uma classe.

Se por exemplo você fizer:

```
public class Foca {
    public int qtdFilhos;
}
```

Significa que cada instância da classe `Foca` (um objeto) terá um valor próprio para a variável `qtdFilhos`.

Nesse código:

```
public class Foca {
    public int qtdFilhos;

    public static void listarFamilia() {
        Foca[] familia = new Foca[qtdFilhos + 2];
    }
}
```

O acesso a variável `qtdFilhos` nesse método não faz sentido, porque a qual dos objetos da classe `Foca` está se referindo? É a mesma situação com a classe `EmpresaTest`. Ao acessar o atributo `TAM`, a qual das instâncias você se refere (sabemos que pode só haver uma ou a uma variável especifica, mas o compilador não)?

Para corrigir o problema você precisa, assim como os demais atributos acima dele, adicionar o modificador `static`, tornando ela uma **variável de classe**.

As **variáveis de classe** são únicas para todas as instâncias de uma classe sobre o mesmo `ClassLoader`.

Isso significa que para qualquer momento durante execução do seu programa, a partir do primeiro acesso, que é onde o `ClassLoader` a inicializa, exceto no caso em que a variável é `final` (a JVM faz uma otimização onde o valor é inicializado junto com o bytecode), qualquer acesso a ela será compartilhado por todos.

Para corrigir o problema mude o seu código para:

```
public class EmpresaTest {
    public static int posicao = 0;
    public static boolean t = true;
    public static final int TAM = 5; // Agora TAM é uma variável de classe

    // Restante do código
}
```